# What is the standard approach for shared home directories for a user across multiple machines?

Tags: environment-variables, binary, shared-library, container

This is kind of a two-part question. In the case where there are multiple machines for which users get a single home directory - i.e. sshing into any of the machines, a user will find the same files in `~/` regardless of which machine they were created on - what is the standard approach to separating files and executables for running different jobs on each machine?

First of all, how can one know whether it is necessary to compile code separately for each machine? Are there comprehensive tests to make sure that an executable won't run differently on a server that wasn't originally used to compile the code?

In the case that compiled code or libraries should not be used across all machines, what is the standard way to separate it in the shared home directory? Is it sufficient to store in separate subdirectories and change `$PATH` variables depending on which server you are logged into? Or can one redefine `$HOME` to point in one of these subdirectories and just operate out of that? Are there tools available for dealing with this sort of situation robustly? Would something like Docker containers be a good choice?

Comment: Usually, `/home` may be mounted on an NFS share. The machines mounting from it are usually homogenous, so problems with different `PATH` is not an issue. You may want to narrow down your question and give specific details.

Comment: Could you give a list of operating systems under consideration? On some, binary compatibility is easier to discern than on others (such as [hardware capabilities](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/hwcap-modification-139536.html) on Solaris and binary compatibility across minor releases on Red Hat).

Comment: Since you are talking about home directories which usually ideally don't have executables, that is almost a non-issue.  If your users wish to compile programs and switch from one machine to another, it seems like it's their responsibility to deal with it.

Comment: I am asking this question as a user. The sysadmin will not install all the software I need to use and I also write software that I compile myself to run on both machines. The processors on each machine are not the same but the architectures are. The OS are the same but not necessarily same version. I think some libraries may be shared across machines but I'm not sure how to tell whether they are. Is there something I can check with new compiled code, like using ld to see if it will run okay with what it's linked to?

Comment: Assuming that other users have had to be responsible for such situations before, what kinds of directory/executable organisation is typically adopted, if any? If there are unknowns about how the machines are setup and compatibility, how do you figure it out and what are the safest practices? I'm asking this as kind of a noob when it comes to sysadmin and filesystems on networked machines.